# Using git-svn to merge a svn branch back into trunk and trunk back into the branch

Tags: svn, git, branch, reintegration

So I'm using git and interacting with an svn repo.

I have a svn TRUNK that looks like this:

```
A-B-C-D
```

And a svn bug_fixes branch that branches off at commit B or C:

```
 -c-d-e-f-g-h-i
```

Now I need to get the cdefghi commits that are in my svn branch back into the master branch.

I'm aware that I could just do a squashed commit, let's call it squash SQUASH (which would contain cdefghi), but then it seems like I would have to kill the bug_fixes branch and start a new branch to cleanly continue.

Here: http://blog.red-bean.com/sussman/?p=92 they suggest:

`checkout` the branch.

`merge` master's changes into the branch.

`Checkout` the master.

`merge --reintegrate` the branch's changes onto master.

Continue development.

Unfortunately, git-svn doesn't seem to recognize any "merge --reintegrate" command for svn.

So how do I cleanly make branch and master have all commits, so that development on both can continue, using git-svn's commands?

Comment: so basically, none of the solutions do an exact reintegration, all leaving the branch in conflict if you keep using it?

Comment: Frankly, looking back at this, i would do one of these two things:  1. Use a git repo without svn.  2. Use a central svn repo, and do all my merging and rebasing in git, without using the less capable svn branches at all.  If I had to share any branches, I'd do so in a git mirror -without- a master branch and keep only the master branch in svn.  But overall I'd dispense with svn if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Caveats section of the `git-svn` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats) warns

> For the sake of simplicity and interoperating with a less-capable system (SVN), it is recommended that all `git svn` users `clone`, `fetch` and `dcommit` directly from the SVN server, and avoid all `git clone`/`pull`/`merge`/`push` operations between git repositories and branches.

The author does provide a recommendation:

> The recommended method of exchanging code between git branches and users is `git format-patch` and `git am`, or just `dcommit`ing to the SVN repository.

Adapting to your situation

```
git format-patch --stdout c^..i >my.patch
git reset --hard trunk
git am <my.patch
```

where `c` and `i` are appropriate identifiers for the commits in your history.

Comment: This allows me to apply all the commits to the trunk, but doesn't allow me to continue developing on the branch.  Unfortunately, since svn has a linear revision history it seems that the recommended course of action is actually to merge the branch in to trunk, then delete the branch and create one of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so a few approaches that I found:

```
git checkout your_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge your_branch
```

or

```
git checkout your_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --squash your_branch
```

or

```
git checkout your_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git rebase -i your_branch
```

And then after all that.

```
git svn dcommit (to commit to master)
git branch -D your_branch
```

Then (from svn because git-svn doesn't support deletion) delete the branch,
and recreate it from trunk and start the cycle all over again.

Comment: how to get branch from svn? it's stored in there.. not in local repo.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of "Git svn fetch" or something. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html

Comment: I think you should really do a `git svn rebase` instead.
It should preserve a linear history according to the documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn-emrebaseem

Answer (score 1):

Would this not be a good case for rebasing your local stuff (`<branchpoint>..i`) onto the new master fetched from SVN?

Comment: That works well in git, but not with svn's linear revision history.  So you can get the changes from branch to trunk, but continuing development on the branch afterwards is apparently futile.

Answer (score 1):

If you dcommit a merge it automatically squashes it into 1 commit. Sadly it does not internally use svn:mergeinfo or --reintegrate as it should, so you lose the association with the branch created via 'git svn branch'.

Answer (score 1):

What you also can do is *cherry-pick*, provided that you wouldn't use *merge*.

Both statements should be done on the branch without the changes.

Provided that c is older than i and that you want to take the whole sequence.

```
git cherry-pick c..i
```

Or separate commits

```
git cherry-pick c d e f g h i
```