# Switch the svn branch git dcommits to

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, branching-and-merging

I had `master` `dcommit` to (and `rebase` from) the Subversion `trunk`.

I created an intermediate Subversion branch `tc`, to merge changes from 2 different branches, using:

```
git branch master
git svn branch tc -m "Branch for merging"
git checkout -b tcl --track tc
git merge cat #Another branch, whose changes I merged here
git commit -m 'Merged changes from cat branch'
git svn dcommit
```

Since everything was fine, I wanted to promote this to the `trunk`. I followed doing:

```
git branch master
git merge tcl
git svn dcommit
```

Now, because `master` was merged from another branch that was pointing to a different Subversion branch, it tries to commit to the Subversion branch `tc`. I want it committed to the Subversion `trunk`.

Is there a `git svn switch` or something like that?

I know my workflow is not the optimal and any suggestions to improve it are welcome too.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but one thing I highly recommend is to always do a `git svn dcommit -n` (dry run) before doing the actual dcommit. One reason for that is so you can make sure you're committing to the svn branch you mean to commit to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164690/using-git-svn-to-merge-a-svn-branch-back-into-trunk-and-trunk-back-into-the-branc), using `git merge` in a repository with `git-svn` is not a good idea.

Instead, what you should have done to "merge" the changes into `master` is:

```
git checkout master
git format-patch --stdout master..tcl | git am
git svn dcommit
```

The problem with `git merge` in this case is that it also sets the `git-svn` URL for `master` to the SVN `tc` branch. The `format-patch` and `am` combination only takes the changes themselves.

Comment: Would a rebase instead of a merge have the same issue?

Comment: You should never rebase anything from an svn branch if you want to dcommit it, because you won't be able to. svn does not support history modification.

Comment: Well, I won't do it next time. But how does it solve the issue if the problem is already there?

Comment: @jlengrand can you explain your question? If you already merged and you want to dcommit you'll have to `git reset` back to before your merge and re-do it with the above method.

Comment: Yes, I had already merged :). I found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835791/git-svn-reset-tracking-for-master in @dyodji answer after a while :). Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK a `--no-ff` merge would have gone the way you want:

```
git branch master
git merge --no-ff tcl
git svn dcommit
```